# Is there a way to make an input only accept one letter in HTML?

Tags: html, input, letter

I'm working on an Wordle remake in HTML, and I want to make separate inputs for each letter, but I don't know how to make the input only accept one letter. Is there any way to make an input only accept one letter?

Comment: You could use a pattern: `<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1}" title="Please enter only one letter"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can.  Using the `maxlength` attribute.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
```

Comment: That would allow any character

Comment: @mplungjan That is true.